# Connecting from ICE to regional trains (Deutsche Bahn)

Tags: trains, germany

Is a 7-minute transfer (from an ICE train to a regional train) too risky? If I can't make it, can I use my ticket to take the next regional train?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit the title of your question? It should *be* the question, or at least describe the question (if it would become too long).

Comment: Could you specify the train station?

Comment: @asdfex The train station is Nuremberg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 7 minutes is pretty risky on DB, although when coming from an ICE and changing onto a regional train, chances are higher that the regional train will wait for passengers from the ICE (compared to an ICE waiting for pax from a regional train, however, without knowing the station, scheduled platforms and details of the specific trains, it's impossible to give an absolute estimate).

Still, I'd suggest you make sure that arriving on the next train won't hurt your further plans.

As for your second question, yes, you can simply take the next train, there is no "Zugbindung" on regional trains, so you can always buy a ticket for the short connection and take the next train if the ICE is running late.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that if you ever miss a connection between two trains on a DB ticket, DB will allow you to take the next train with the same ticket. You can additionally ask the station staff for a stamp to highlight this fact. Additionally the time to walk between stations is relatively small in German train stations.

Answer (score 3):

- There are some stations, especially in larger cities, where 7 minutes is not enough between some of the platforms. Check the numbers, if they are close to each other it might be possible.
- If you miss the connection because the train is late, you are entitled to a partial refund on your ticket price if you arrive at the final destination more than one hour late. Get a Fahrgastrechteformular and get it stamped either on the train or at the station to confirm that you were late, you can send it in or get cash at the train station.

Comment: On the other hand, there are plenty connections where you just cross the platform and one minute would be enough.

Comment: Also keep in mind that track numbers are not nessassary sequential.

Answer (score 2):

The Nuernberg station only has one level with tracks, but you need to go downstairs from the platform to get to the others, and the walk is long if you have luggage.

If the train is on time, you can make the distance between the first and the last platform easily in two to three minutes if you know the station. Essentially you find the nearest stairs, go down, look left and right to see the number of the platform you are looking for. They are numbered in ascending order, with large blue signs next to the stairs.

[Here's a map view](https://www.google.de/maps/place/N%C3%BCrnberg+Hbf/@49.4451831,11.0819448,210m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x479f57a7519a1567:0x530339666394c005!8m2!3d49.4462303!4d11.0819421?hl=en) of the station, indicating the platforms. [This photo on maps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/N%C3%BCrnberg+Hbf/@49.4464046,11.0806975,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPkURvNIqbSFsvmAdN6FTnlVuJJ97fB_E9qywHa!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPkURvNIqbSFsvmAdN6FTnlVuJJ97fB_E9qywHa%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i4128!8i3096!4m5!3m4!1s0x479f57a7519a1567:0x530339666394c005!8m2!3d49.4462303!4d11.0819421?hl=en) shows the entrance to the tunnel under the platforms, where you can also see the platform sings.

When you go downstairs from your platform where you arrive, [there are already signs](https://www.google.de/maps/place/N%C3%BCrnberg+Hbf/@49.4467248,11.0815099,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPHEBTaKpWIgvYSEn9aJoMUCVUmmP5b1PQS2Pa7!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPHEBTaKpWIgvYSEn9aJoMUCVUmmP5b1PQS2Pa7%3Dw203-h360-k-no!7i2268!8i4032!4m5!3m4!1s0x479f57a7519a1567:0x530339666394c005!8m2!3d49.4462303!4d11.0819421?hl=en) that show what way you need to turn.

[The tunnel looks like this](https://www.google.de/maps/place/N%C3%BCrnberg+Hbf/@49.4464046,11.0806975,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNmDoptVBvy8M5RcANEakyI_zP_KstWAqqMuSTF!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNmDoptVBvy8M5RcANEakyI_zP_KstWAqqMuSTF%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i4032!8i3024!4m5!3m4!1s0x479f57a7519a1567:0x530339666394c005!8m2!3d49.4462303!4d11.0819421?hl=en).

I believe even with luggage, 7 minutes is enough to navigate this with signs. If your train is late however, you should inform the staff on your previous leg that you have to make the connection at least ten to 15 minutes before arriving in Nuernberg. They will either make the other train wait, or find an alternative connection for you.